# Function with an arc

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to recreate this graphic.

[image]

I know that my method is archaic and somewhat wrong, I'm asking if is there a better way to replicate the above represented `function` without having to quasi-manually draw it as I'm currently doing with `curve through points`.

The explanation:

The function isn't defined with a formula, but it represents distance between the amplitude of a signal and what is called the noise floor (noise with constance amplitude) of the output of an analog-to-digital converter. As the signal's amplitude grows, it distances itself from the noise linearly. Thus the first part of the function. But then it growth stops being linear, then achieves it's peak, following with the saturation of the analog-to-digital converter and abrupt decrease in the distance between the signal's amplitude and the noise floor.

Here's my attempt with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.5mm]}] (0,0)--(6,0) node[anchor=north]{};
        \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.5mm]}] (0,0)--(0,6) node[anchor=east]{};
        \node[anchor=south, rotate=90] at (-0.5,3) {$SNR,~SNDR~[dB]$};
        \node[anchor=north] at (3,-0.5) {$Input~Signal~Amplitude~[dBv]$};
        \node[anchor=north east] at (0,0) {0};

        \draw (0,0) -- (4,4);
        \draw (4,4) to [curve through ={(4.2,4) . . (4.5,3.6)}] (5,2);% curve
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Performance metrics.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just plot functions. If you provide some more background where this plot comes from, I will find a better function. What I'm doing here is to plot an elliptical arc. I am using functions for this, but you could equally well just use the `arc` syntax provided by Ti*k*Z. The reason for the elliptical arcs is that your functions seem to become vertical at x_max/2. And the reason for drawing functions is that I suspect that you have a theory behind these plots and will ultimately feed the plot with real functions. (And I'm assuming that you do not have difficulties in drawing the additional features.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
I guess that has now become more a mathematics problem. Let's assume you really
want a function that starts off at $(x_1,y_1)$ somewhere with slope 1 and then
has slope $-\infty$ at some other place. This defines an elliptical arc, which
can be parametrized by
\[ \gamma(\varphi)~=~\left(\begin{array}{c}
 x_0+a\,\cos(\varphi)\\ b\,\sin(\varphi)
\end{array}\right)\;.\]
Here, we have set a possible shift in $y$ direction to 0 since we want the slope
to become infinite when the curve hits the $x$--axis.
What is the angle at which the slope is 1? The slope is given by the ratio of
the derivatives of the coordinates, such that
\[ -\frac{b\,\cos(\varphi_1)}{a\,\sin(\varphi_1)}~\stackrel{!}{=}~1
\quad\curvearrowright\quad \varphi_1~=~-\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\;.
\]
Now we want at the same time that
\[ \gamma(\varphi)~=~\left(\begin{array}{c}
 x_0+a\,\cos(\varphi_1)\\ b\,\sin(\varphi_1)
\end{array}\right)~=~
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_0-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2}}\\
\frac{b/a}{\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2}}
\end{array}\right)
~\stackrel{!}{=}~
\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\ y_1\end{array}\right)\;.\]
This means that we can only adjust one parameter, say $b$, and the other
parameters are then fixed by
\[
 a^2~=~\frac{b}{y_1}\,\sqrt{b^2-y_1^2}\quad\text{and}\quad
 x_0~=~x_1-y_1+\frac{b^2}{y_1}\;.
\]
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.5mm]}] (0,0)--(6,0) node[anchor=north]{};
        \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.5mm]}] (0,0)--(0,6) node[anchor=east]{};
        \node[anchor=south, rotate=90] at (-0.5,3) {SNR,~SNDR~[dB]};
        \node[anchor=north] at (3,-0.5) {Input~Signal~Amplitude~[dBv]};
        \node[anchor=north east] at (0,0) {0};

        \draw (0,0) -- (4,4);
        % in these examples I have set x_1 = y_1 = 4
        \def\xOne{4}
        \def\b{4.15}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\b*sqrt((\b^2-\xOne^2))/4}
        \draw[name path=upper plot] plot[variable=\x,domain=180-atan(\b/\a):0,samples=50] 
        ({\xOne-(\xOne-\b^2/\xOne)+\a*cos(\x)},{\b*sin(\x)});
        \coordinate (max1) at({\xOne-(\xOne-\b^2/\xOne)+\a*cos(90)},{\b*sin(90)});
        \def\b{3.9}
        \def\xOne{3.7}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{\b*sqrt((\b^2-\xOne^2))/\xOne}
        \draw[dashed,name path=lower plot] plot[variable=\x,domain=180-atan(\b/\a):0,samples=50] 
        ({\xOne-(\xOne-\b^2/\xOne)+\a*cos(\x)},{\b*sin(\x)});
        \coordinate (max2) at
        ({\xOne-(\xOne-\b^2/\xOne)+\a*cos(90)},{\b*sin(90)});
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \draw[dotted] (O|-max1) -- (max1) node[above,pos=0.7]{SNR$_\mathrm{peak}$} --(O-|max1);
        \path [name path=horizontal 2] (max2) -- ++(2cm,0);
        \draw [dotted,name intersections={of=upper plot and horizontal 2, by={a0}}]
         (a0) -- ++(-2cm,0) node[left]{SNDR$_\mathrm{peak}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Performance metrics.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
You can adjust one parameter, \b, in order to control the arc. And it is straightforward to read off the maximum and so on, and you can use Ti*k*Z to do all sorts of stuff with it, as illustrated.

Comment: I added some info about the function. And I have no problem in adding the other features, it is just the ploted function.

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting an answer with such detail!